# How to use IF with iMacro in Firefox?

Tags: image, firefox, if-statement, macros, click

I am not a programmer and I use iMacro for this but I have one problem:

Each time a page loads, it loads 1 out of 4 images randomly, each image has different name, you can't see image name in address (I see it using tools >>> page info >>> media), I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this:

Make iMacro click on different place on image based on that image name? (each image has a hidden element that can be clicked, position is fixed though)

Please help ???